# Is a SSH key tied to a username?

Tags: ssh

As far as I know, if a client wants to connect to a server, client add it's `public` key to the servers `authorized_keys` file under a specific user on the server. Then the client can connect to the server like this:

```
ssh user@server.com
```

My question, is there a way to accomplish this:

```
ssh server.com
```

And server picks the user based on the provided key somehow?

Comment: ssh will default to the current username (the user running ssh) when no username is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public key is placed into the home directory of the user on the server who used `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` to generate it and put it there. If you use ssh to connect to the machine with no username, it will attempt to connect with the username of whoever is logged in. If the logged in user doesn't have a key on the server, then it will attempt password authentication. If password authentication is disabled and the user doesn't have a key, the login will fail. This is assuming that the user has login and ssh access to the machine.

Comment: Dont forget the command `ssh -i /path/to/alternate/key` for those examples where you need a script call a program on a remote machine. Like for instance `rsync`.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an alias in `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host server
    Hostname server.com or the IP
    User username
    Port ssh-port
```

And then connect just as `ssh server`.